# Want to parse a csv file in google cloud storage using nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

Csv file contents:

```
###(BucketName)  (FileName)  (BigQuery-DatasetName) (BigQuery-TargetTable)             
A          A.csv           sample_dataset              A
A          B.csv           sample_dataset              B
B          C.csv           sample_dataset              C
B          D.csv           test_dataset                D
```

csv file in google cloud storage consists of a mapping of GCS(Source File's) 
with the destination(Big Query Table Name's). I want to parse each column 
name and based on that want to ingest the data into BiqQuery Table.If incase 
the table is not present in the Big Query we have to create it dynamically.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: I had fixed this issue long back.